# remove ' months' from int in 'term column' example '36 months'

Tags: python, pandas

Need to split the int and string in a 'loan term column' example: '36 months', and discard the string, leaving only the int 36.
 From '36 months' to 36 ' months' to 36

I have been all over the internet looking for a solution,
but the search engine looks at the column title and give urls
with date solutions.

```
def remove_months(string):
  return int(string.strip(' months'))
df['term'] = df['term'].apply(remove_months)
```

The first two lines of code runs (do not give an error).
, but the third line gives an error.

Attribute Error: 'None Type' object has no attribute 'strip'

I need to convert the string to an integer and remove the string in the column. example: From '36 months' to 36 ' months' to 36

Comment: How are you generating "36 months"? Maybe just output "36" if that's what you need. Otherwise, a regex would work.

Comment: how about `df['term'].str.extract('(\d+)',expand=False)` ?

Comment: Eurecal Federal Saved Me.  You got it @anky_91. You solution worked.

Comment: Thank you again @anky_91.  I looked for this, but could not find it here, It's how one words the question that makes the dif. But you, have all the answers.  You solved my deelambda. Thank you again.

Comment: @2tan2ten Pleasure :) happy coding

Comment: OOOPS. Guess what, that extracted the integer, but did not work,

Comment: Assign it back to df['term'] =...